# Unity object rotation speed differs on device

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, touch, transform

I have an object that I rotate left or right as the user drags their finger over it and on an iPad4 this works perfectly smooth.

However on an iPhone 6 Plus or a Nexus 4 there is a very obvious lag in responding to the drag to the point sometimes it hardly rotates?

This is what I have in my update method...am I doing something wrong re making sure the rotation feel and look work the same across devices?

```
void Update () {

    // test for touch 
    if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

        // grab reference to this touch
        Touch userTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        // ray from cameara to point of finger touch
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( Input.GetTouch(0).position );

        // hit object to record details of what was hit (touched)
        RaycastHit hit;

        // if the hit was on the Collider object
        if ( Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject.name == "MyObject") {

            // process the relavent phase...
            if (userTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            }
            else if (userTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

                // user is moving finger so rotate model
                transform.Rotate(0.0f, -userTouch.deltaPosition.x * _rotationSpeed, 0, Space.Self); 
            }
            else if (userTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || userTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-userTouch.deltaPosition.x * _rotationSpeed * time.deltaTime
```

**time.deltaTime**

time.deltaTime will ensure that there's no dipendence with framerate, since "deltaTime" refers on how much time passed from the last frame. It's common use to add always time.deltaTime on calculations in the Update method, especially the ones that involves movement or time-counting

Comment: Or you can update the rotation/position in the FixedUpdate method. But using deltaTime is the way-to-go most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys ;-)  appreciated ;-)